# Avoiding Public methods in another class?

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

I have 2 forms and 1 Class.
I made the class a Static Class.
It has two methods with public modifiers.
Ex: Public string PrintHello(), Public void Task1()

I want these methods to be accessible from both Form1 and Form2.
I understand that using "Public" modifier is not good, so I've looked at "Internal" modifier and it seems to do the job.

Basically, I want to create a secure way of accessing my class.
What would be the best way of doing so and could you provide an example of how to do so ?

Thank you

Comment: Define "secure". Secure from what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access modifiers does not provide security to you code.
Is someone really wants to use your privet methods he can use ILDASM to de-compile your code and use them, that would be just one example of many.

Access modifiers are there to to allow you to program using with an Object Oriented code design.
In general:
Private modifiers are internal to your class implementation and other classes or layers of your code dose not **NEED nor want** to know about there existence.

Internal modifiers are there to provide additional functionality required for the whole assembly but again they are not required for any one else (outside of the assembly) because they are implementation specific.

And finally Public modifiers are used to define the interface of your class with the outside world, these are methods and properties that should and will be used by any one that requires some sor of functionality from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you think the code that calls this methods will likely live. If it is only going to be ever called from the class that defined this method, then it should be private. If you only want to call it from the same assembly (dll) but you don't want to call the methods from other dlls, then you should make it internal. This way you can ship your dll to other projects and you don't have to worry about supporting your methods (because they won't have access to your methods).

But if you are doing a general purpose libarary/dll etc. Then the methods should be public.

It all depends on who or what you think is going to call your methods.